# Maximum PNG size according to resolution

Tags: compression, png

Is there a way to calculate the Maximum size that could take any image compressed with PNG ?

I need to know, that (for example) a PNG of a resolution of 350x350 (px), can't be larger than "X" KB. (and for a constant quality compression, like 90)

the "X" value is the one I'm looking for. Or in math expression

```
350px *  350px * (90q) < X KB
```

I'm not quite familiar with the PNG compression algorithm, but there is probably a max value for a specific resolution ?

P.S. : the PNG has no alpha is this case.

Comment: Related, probably dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502529/worst-png-compression-scenario

Comment: You are right ! I didn't have the correct Tags when searching for my issue.

Comment: Do not mix up 'resolution' and 'size'. *Resolution* is an absolute value: the number of pixels per (absolute) measurement unit. A typical unit is "pixels per inch", or 'ppi'. What you are asking about is *size*, in pixels *only*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [PNG format here:](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/iso/index-object.html#11CcGen)

The maximum case happens when the data is incompressible
(for example, if the image resolution is 1x1,
or if the image is larger but contains random incompressible data).

That would make the maximum size:

```js
   8 // PNG signature bytes
+ 25 // IHDR chunk (Image Header)
+ 12 // IDAT chunk (assuming only one IDAT chunk)
+ height // in pixels
  * (
        1 // filter byte for each row
      + (
         width // in pixels
         * 3   // Red, blue, green color samples
         * 2   // 16 bits per color sample
        )
    )
+  6 // zlib compression overhead
+  2 // deflate overhead
+ 12 // IEND chunk
```

Compression "quality" doesn't enter into this.

Most applications will probably separate the `IDAT` chunk into smaller chunks, typically 8 kbytes each, so in the case of a 350x350 image there would be 44 IDAT chunks, so add 43*12 for IDAT chunk overhead.

As a check, a 1x1 16-bit RGB image can be written as a 72-byte PNG, and a 1x1 8-bit grayscale image is 67 bytes.

If the image is interlaced, or has any ancillary chunks, or has an alpha channel, it will naturally be bigger.

Comment: Oops, I forgot that I had answered a duplicate of this question last year.  There, I said that the deflate overhead was 5 bytes, but my tests here indicate that it can be only 2 bytes.  I must have mixed up bits and bytes while reading rfc-1951.

Comment: Taking it to its extremes: is an IDAT chunk of 1 byte length valid? Nothing in the specifications seems to indicate that it isn't ... so you can add a *whopping* overhead of 12 bytes per chunk - each chunk a single input byte! I guess it depends on why OP (thinks he) needs to know this.

Comment: @Jongware, Yes, a PNG with a number of 1-byte data (or even zero-byte data) IDAT chunks is valid; the decoder concatenates their contents to obtain the zlib datastream.